# How does EF know the name of the joining table in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: entity-framework

I've started working on a mature code-first EF6 project. There is no EDMX file. I can't find anywhere in the code where the names of the joining tables that support many-to-many relationships is specified, and yet EF knows what they are. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EF model is built by a set of [conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/conventions/built-in), which you can override with attributes or code-based configuration.